# Copy certain properties from two lists into third list

Tags: c#

I've a list A

Class A {id, name, location, post, station, status, rank}

I've a list B

Class B {gender, level}

I want list A and list B should be both merged and copied over onto List C. So that List C would be like this

Class C {id, name, status, gender, level}

Comment: What does "merged and copied" mean to you regarding these lists? You should read [ask].

Comment: So why don't you do that? Do you actually have any data? Show it. Have you written any code at all? You have, but you're getting an error? Post the error.

Comment: Are you referring to "List" as being a class `List<T>`or a list as in `[ElementA, ElementB]`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First: refering to a class and a list with the same name is confusing. I reference to them as `listA` and `class A`

This is not possible without `listA` and `listB` sharing a property to merge them on.

If `class B` consisted of `{id, gender, level}` where `id` was the same as `id` from `class A` you could do:

```
var bDic = listB.ToDictionary(a => a.id, a => a); // for faster searching
var listC = listA.Select(a => new C()
{
   id = a.id,
   name = a.name,
   status = a.status,
   gender = bDic[a.id].gender,
   level = bDic[a.id].level,
}
.ToList();
```

Comment: Please [don't answer bad questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267540/). Even if, by some miracle, your answer is exactly what the questioner wants, doing this rewards people for asking others to do their work without providing any sample code, input, or output. It won't help anyone else either, as the chance that someone with the same problem would search for “Copy certain properties ...” is nil. Instead, vote to close, and add a comment prompting for the information that would make the question answerable and useful.

Comment: Don't answer "gimme teh codez" questions, it just encourages them.